# Hashicorp Vault Required Provider Configuration in Terraform

Tags: gitlab, terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

My GitLab CI  pipeline terraform configuration requires a couple of required_provider blocks to be declared. These are "hashicorp/azuread" and "hashicorp/vault" and so in my provider.tf file, I have given the below declaration:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
         azuread = {
                    source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
                    version = "~> 2.0.0"
          }
    
         vault = {
                    source = "hashicorp/vault"
                    version = "~> 3.0.0"
          }
    }
}
```

When my GitLab pipeline runs the terraform plan stage however, it throws the following error:

```
Error: Invalid provider configuration

Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault" requires explicit configuraton. 
Add a provider block to the root module and configure the providers required 
arguments as described in the provider documentation.
```

I realise my required provider block for hashicorp/vault is incomplete/not properly configured but despite all my efforts to find an example of how it should be configured, I have simply run into a brick wall.

Any help with a very basic example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Terraform you are using. However, for each provider there is (in the top right corner) a `Use Provider` button which explains how to add the required blocks of code to [your files](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest).

[image]

Each provider has some additional configuration parameters which could be added and some are required.

So based on the error, I think you are missing the second part of the configuration:

```
provider "vault" {
 # Configuration options
}
```

There is also an explanation on how to [upgrade to version 3.0 of the provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/guides/version_3_upgrade). You might also want to take a look at [Hashicorp Learn examples](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/codify-mgmt-oss) and [Github repo with example code](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-guides).